# How to preserve home made garlic sauce for at least two years shelf life?

Tags: sauce, oil, food-preservation, garlic

I am thinking of starting a business selling home made garlic sauce. The sauce contains both, oil and water as well as lemon juice. How can I prevent it from spoiling and extend its shelf life?

Comment: A lot to getting the proper licenses.  And you probably need to use a commercial kitchen.   Create an LLC in case you kill someone.

Answer (score 4):

Pressure canning would probably be your only option, as you will want to eliminate the potential for botulism, primarily.

Comment: Pressure canning at 15 PSI for 30 minutes at least. If you are in the USA, you'll also require FDA lous recapproval of your product, your process and your label then you and your meticulous records of every batch will be inspected for compliance at least once a year.
You will also be required to meet all state and food sanitation laws and regulations.